# Mouse hover stops d3 bar moving

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, input, mouse

Im having a d3 bar chart that sorts its bars whenever the user choses certain settings. My Problem is, that when it starts sorting itself and the mouse is moved over the bars while they are still sorting themselves, the bars "touched" with the mouse stop where they are and it looks like this:

http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=1dd214-1457697725.png

Here are parts of my code:

```
var margin2 = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 0},
width2 = 1750 - margin2.left - margin2.right,
height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width2], .1, 1);

var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y2)
.orient("left");
var yAxis22 = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y2)
.orient("right");

var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width2 + margin2.left + margin2.right)
.attr("height", height2 + margin2.top + margin2.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top +")");
```

and then in an updating function where I erase the d3 elements i want to change and then display them again the following is called:

```
d3.csv(dataC, function(error, data) {
if (chan == true){


x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);


}   
svg2.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
  .call(xAxis2);

svg2.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate("+""+width2+",0)")
  .call(yAxis2)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
  .attr("y2", 100)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end");
svg2.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")
  .call(yAxis22)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
  .attr("y2", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "front");
if (chan == true){
svg2.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y2(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height2 - y2(d.frequency); })
  .on("click", function(d){
        getCountry(d);
    })
  .on("mouseover", function() {
      d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill", "orange");})
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
       .transition()
       .duration(550)
       .attr("fill", "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")");
    });

 d3.select("input").on("change", change);

 var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
 d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
 }, 500) }
 function change() {
  clearTimeout(sortTimeout);

  if (chan == true){
  // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
  var x02 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked
    ? function(a, b) { return b.frequency - a.frequency; }
    : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter); })
    .map(function(d) { return d.letter; }))
    .copy();

  svg2.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(function(a, b) { return x02(a.letter) - x02(b.letter); });

  var transition = svg2.transition().duration(750),
    delay = function(d, i) { return i * 10; };

  transition.selectAll("rect")
    .delay(delay)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x02(d.letter); });

  transition.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis2)
  .selectAll("g")
    .delay(delay);
  chan = false;
   }
  }
 });
 }
```

I guess it because i have a mouse input, and i also have radio buttons working with mouse input like:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"
onchange="headerChange('acco.csv')"/>
<label for="radio2">Accomodation</label>
```

Is there a way to STOP the mouse input on the bars while they are sorting themselves or is there a totally diffrent problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Regards,
Florence

Comment: The most likely issue would be that you're overriding the current transition with the `mouseout` transition. If this is the case there's an easy fix, you can read about transitions here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions. Specifically, you would want to name your transitions. As an example, for a svg circle element called `circ`, you would do `circ.transition("horizTransition").duration(1000).attr("cx", 200);`
and `circ.transition("vertTransition").duration(2000).attr("cy", 200);`. Both of the transitions will complete without overriding the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked!